# Can I specify multiple minimum versions in a Gem specification

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I'm working on a gem that has multiple minimum versions (it'll work on Rails with different major versions, but for security and other reasons it shouldn't be used on lower minor version levels). I'd like it to require at least (for example):

```
Rails 3.2.19
Rails 4.0.8
Rails 4.1.4
```

I can see from [RubyGems Guides](http://guides.rubygems.org/patterns/) that I can use twiddle-wakka and Greater-Than-Or-Equal-To to get me, for example, a minimum of 3.2.19 - but that then, I think, precludes me also asking for an alternative of 4.0.8, or 4.1.4. This WORKS for 3.2.19 as a minimum in a Gemfile, so long as I want 3.2.x and not 4.0.x or 4.1.x:

```
gem 'rails', '~> 3.2', '>= 3.2.19'
```

In the gemspec, the next runtime dependency shown below, FAILS to match both 4.0.8 or 4.1.4, even if both are installed and locally available:

```
s.add_runtime_dependency('rails', ['~> 4.0', '>= 4.0.8', '~> 4.1', '>= 4.1.4'])
```

with bundler saying:

```
#{my-gem} (= 1.0.0) ruby depends on
  rails (>= 4.0.8, >= 4.1.4, ~> 4.0, ~> 4.1) ruby
rails (4.0.8)
```

bundler sees my installed 4.0.8 or 4.1.4, and says that it fails to meet the requirement. Mildly surprising, as 4.1.4 matches the uppermost requirement - but presumably fails the wakka test of being like 4.0.

Maybe I need three requirement lines rather than a single composite line?

```
s.add_runtime_dependency('rails', ['~> 4.1', '>= 4.1.4'])
s.add_runtime_dependency('rails', ['~> 4.0', '>= 4.0.8'])
s.add_runtime_dependency('rails', ['~> 3.2', '>= 3.2.19'])
```

That also fails. And switching the order of the requirements lines doesn't help (e.g. that's ordered from highest to lowest, ordering from lowest to highest also fails to match).

Is it possible to specify a minimum version of two or more revisions, or is that simply a use-case that hasn't been considered? How should I create a gemspec that allows a gem to support 3.2.19, 4.0.8 and 4.1.4 - but not lower rev versions?

Perhaps I should just be speccing Rails >= 3.2.19 and not trying to push users to specific minimums in other later revs of Rails (even though, arguably, 4.0.0 is a lesser version than 3.2.19 - at least in terms of security)? Am I just overthinking the whole thing?

Context: ruby 1.9.3, 2.1.2; bundler 1.6.2, Rails 3.2.19, 4.0.8 or 4.1.4

Comment: It's definitely not possible now to do this, but you can still fail or log something to the command line by inspecting the Rails version manually so the user know they're using unsafe stuff.